# Promise Dependency using Bluebird

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, bluebird

I want to run a dynamic list of async things in parallel where some of things require other things to be finished first, then have access to all aggregated results.  So far I came up with iterating through multidim. array of the operations, but it needs wrapping function/closure so I am not fully happy with it.  I'm wondering what else people are doing for this situation.

```
var runAllOps = function(ops) {
    var all = []; // counter for results

    var runOperations = function runOperations(ops) {
        var set = ops.shift();
        return Promise.map(set, function(op){
            return op.getData.call(null, op.name)
        })
        .then(function(results){
            all.push(results)
            if (ops.length){
                return runOperations(ops)
            } else {
                return _.flatten(all)
            }
        })
    }

    return runOperations(ops)
}
```

The operations looks like this:

```
var operations = [
    [
        {name: 'getPixieDust', getData: someAsyncFunction},
        {name: 'getMandrake', getData: etc},
    ],
    [
        {name: 'makePotion', getData: brewAsync}
    ]   
]
```

Is there some good way to map dependencies with promises?  It would be nice to be able something like:

```
makePotion: [getPixieDust, getMandrake]
```

then pass the whole thing off to something which knows getPixieDust and getMandrake are to be finished first before calling makePotion.  Instead of current implementation of just puting the dependent operations in the later arrays

Comment: We've actually discussed adding something like this to Bluebird in the past (with getters). Here's what I'd do - if getData on makePotion requires getData on getPixieDust - have getPixieDust call the promise itself on `makePotion` and cache it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no automatic way to do this in Bluebird or any other promise library I know of. Simply put - you do this by building the tree yourself.

Here is how I deal with this issue. First of all, let's cache results:

```
var pixieDustP = null;
function getPixieDust(){
    return pixieDustP || (pixieDustP = apiCallReturningPromise());
}

var mandrakeP = null;
function getMandrake(){
    return mandrakeP || (mandrakeP = apiCallReturningPixieDustPromise());
}

function makePotion(){
    return Promise.join(getMandrake(),getPixieDust(),function(dust,mandrake){
        // do whatever with both, this is ok since it'll call them both.
        // this should also probably be cached.
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good.  Only thing (my example breaks down here kinda) is that 'ingredient list' could be dynamic - making .join problematic. Any ideas for this situation, when you want to dynamically add a new dependency somewhere?  (like in my orig, I'd just add new opration to array, and the rest of code is unchanged) Also- ca you elaborate on the need for caching?  If you have any links to the git discussions about addingsimilar to bluebird I'd love to check it out too.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: You can use `.all` instead of `.join` there, `.join` is just faster and does `.all([..]).spread`, if the ingrediant list is dynamic you can certainly use `.all` instead. Adding a dependency dynamically is just `.then`ing it.  I don't have a git discussion it was discussed on IRC, the closest I have is https://gist.github.com/petkaantonov/ff78fed43146e33a0657 but there isn't a lot of context to it :)

Comment: thank you for your work, good material to check out there.  :D  But still I am unclear why to cache the results.

Comment: Oh, the work is mostly (read _all_) Petka. Caching the results was just in case each promise is a dependency of multiple promises so you don't want to make several API calls each time - your mileage might vary.